# Google map & fusion heat map not showing

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables, heatmap

I have a Fusion table and inside fusion tables I can visualize it and the "display as heatmap" works fine. But as soon as I make a google map following the code examples at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap it doesn't work (yes, I've used the right table Id and it's shared as the map with only markers works fine). I've also copied the code from the javascript+html tab for the example heatmap, but everything I get is a html that is blank.

I'm really confused on why the heatmap won't work.

This is the code for the fusion table map with the fusion table data with markers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
   html, body, #map-canvas { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layerl0;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.145359594889875, 14.900421375462382),
        zoom: 9
      });
      var style = [
        {
          featureType: 'all',
          elementType: 'all',
          stylers: [
            { saturation: -70 }
          ]
        }
      ];
      var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
        map: map,
        name: 'Styled Map'
      });
      map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
      map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
      layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "'col2'",
          from: 'iLyOjPD3jRuyvv3lIVcJ5edgVPhgaNNelo'
        },
        dissipating: true,
    map: map,
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would really appriciate any Ideas why the heat maps wont work (even with the sample code from Google).

Comment: you forgot to add the option `heatmap: {
      enabled: true
    }`

Comment: Also note: when you use any of the google-examples you must change the href of the stylesheet to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css , otherwise the stylesheet can't be loaded and the #map_canvas will have no height(that's why you don't see anything)

Comment: One more point: "dissipating: true" is a setting for the client-side heatmap API, but not for FusionTablesLayers.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for the second tip. I know that the code above lacks the option with the heatmpa. I've tried with it but it didn't work. So I followed your advice about changing the link for the stylsheet from one of the examples and then changed the table id and now it works.

Comment: It seems the FusionTablesLayer heatmap option is simply a buggy and limited feature: I cannot make it do anything sensible with different datasets.